# How can macro variable capture happen with a gensym symbol?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning common lisp. I have written a version of the `once-only` macro, which suffers from an unusual variable capture problem.

My macro is this:

```
(defmacro my-once-only (names &body body)
  (let ((syms (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (gensym))
                      names)))
    ``(let (,,@(mapcar #'(lambda (sym name) ``(,',sym ,,name))
                      syms names))
        ,(let (,@(mapcar #'(lambda (name sym) `(,name ',sym))
                      names syms))
           ,@body))))
```

The canonical version of `only-once` is this:

```
(defmacro once-only ((&rest names) &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop for n in names collect (gensym))))
    `(let (,@(loop for g in gensyms collect `(,g (gensym))))
      `(let (,,@(loop for g in gensyms for n in names collect ``(,,g ,,n)))
        ,(let (,@(loop for n in names for g in gensyms collect `(,n ,g)))
           ,@body)))))
```

The difference, as far as I can tell, is that the canonical version generates new symbols for every expansion of the macro using `only-once`. For example:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(once-only (foo) foo))
(LET ((#:G824 (GENSYM)))
  `(LET (,`(,#:G824 ,FOO))
     ,(LET ((FOO #:G824))
        FOO)))
T
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(my-once-only (foo) foo))
`(LET (,`(,'#:G825 ,FOO))
   ,(LET ((FOO '#:G825))
      FOO))
T
```

The variable my macro uses to store the value of `foo` is the same for every expansion of this form, in this case it would be `#:G825`. This is akin to defining a macro like the following:

```
(defmacro identity-except-for-bar (foo)
  `(let ((bar 2))
     ,foo))
```

This macro captures `bar`, and this capture manifests when `bar` is passed to it, like so:

```
CL-USER> (let ((bar 1))
           (identity-except-for-bar bar))
2
```

However, I cannot think of any way to pass `#:G825` to a macro that uses `my-only-once` so that it breaks like this, because the symbols `gensym` returns are unique, and I cannot create a second copy of it outside of the macro. I assume that capturing it is unwanted, otherwise the canonical version wouldn't bother adding the additional layer of `gensym`. How could capturing a symbol like `#:G826` be a problem? Please provide an example where this capture manifests.

Comment: Sometimes macros "overgensym" the situation. Many Lisp macros that assiduously use `(gensym)` could be written using static gensyms. However, then the author has to prove that nothing is wrong.

Comment: Also, debugging can get very confusing if two different symbols have the same printed representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can demonstrate a behavioral difference between `my-once-only` and `once-only`:

Let's store our test form in a variable.

```
(defvar *form* '(lexalias a 0 (lexalias b (1+ a) (list a b))))
```

This test form exercises a macro called `lexalias`, which we will define in two ways. First with `once-only`:

```
(defmacro lexalias (var value &body body)
  (once-only (value)
    `(symbol-macrolet ((,var ,value))
       ,@body)))

(eval *form*) -> (0 1)
```

Then with `my-once-only`:

```
(defmacro lexalias (var value &body body)
  (my-once-only (value)
    `(symbol-macrolet ((,var ,value))
       ,@body)))

(eval *form*) -> (1 1)
```

Oops! The problem is that under `my-once-only`, both `a` and `b` end up being `symbol-macrolet` aliases for exactly the same `gensym`; the returned expression `(list a b)` ends up being something like `(list #:g0025 #:g0025)`.

**If you're writing a macro-writing helper that implements once-only evaluation, you have no idea how the symbol is going to be used by the code which calls the macro, whose author uses your once-only tool. There are two big unknowns: the nature of the macro and of its use.**

As you can see, if you don't make fresh gensyms, it will not work correctly in all conceivable scenarios.